# Инструменты для скрипта на Windows

Tags: windows

подскажите пожалуйста. Подскажите возможные инструменты, хотелось бы открывать сайт, в поиске вбивать по очереди нужные параметры и в найденных окнах переходить по интерактивнмоу меню. Может быть есть какой-то кликер, который в нужные места экрана нажимает?)) Я со скриптами такого уровня не работал просто. И что вообще нужно знать о системе\сайте что-бы такое реализовать?

Comment: Кто-то хочет написать бота, чтобы он за него кликал по платным ссылкам?

Comment: Нет, просто хочу упростить себе работу. Спасибо поищу.

Comment: Тогда тебе копать в сторону `python`.